# How do I close a JIRA Issue Collector window after I have clicked "Submit" or "Close"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jira

I am working on a webapp that uses framesets and I am trying to implement a Jira Issue Collector. Jira Issue collectors don't play nice with webapps that use framesets. More Detail Here. So I have created a workaround that pops the Issue collector into a new window. More Detail Here. Now I can close the issue collector window but a blank webpage stays open once the issue collector has been closed. Is there any way to make the window close with the issue collector?

Link that pops my javascript into a new window

```html
<td class="menu2norm" width="80" align="center"><a href="javascript:IssueCollector();" class="menu2">Provide Feedback</a></td>
```

JavaScript code for Issue collector

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "JIRA ISSUE COLLECTOR URL",
                    type: "get",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "script"
                });

                window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = {
                    "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
                        $(this).on('load', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            showCollectorDialog();
                        });
                    }
                };

                window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {
                    fieldValues: {
                        fullname : '<%=Session("LoggedFirstName") & " " & Session("LoggedLastName")%>',
                        email : '<%=Session("LoggedEmail")%>',
                    }                  
                });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and has been resolved as "Won't Fix".

See the bug: [Issue Collector Cannot Be Closed When Placed Inside a Frameset](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-29886).